# Как очистить историю загрузок в Android?

Tags: android, download

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно очистить историю загрузок в Android (или не писать их туда) программным образом? Дело в том, что для загрузки файлов используется DownloadManager, файлы шифрованные и кроме как приложения-загрузчика никому больше не нужны, поэтому не хотелось бы их видеть в системном разделе "Загрузки", тем более что их может быть 1000+ со временем.

UPD:

Выяснил, что у **android.app.DownloadManager.Request** можно установить **setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)**. Но в документации написано:

> "Set whether this download should be displayed in the system's Downloads UI. True by default."

Поэтому не работает в некоторых телефонах, так как там используется не стандартный менеджер загрузок (например SGS).

Comment: можете просто не использовать DownloadManager. Он используется какраз тогда, когда пользователю нужно показывать прогресс, и давать пользоваться закачанными файлами

Comment: я бы с радостью, но помимо прогресса DownloadManager следит за поэтапной загрузкой в случае загрузки большого файла, а так же следит за тем, что если сервер поддерживает сжатие, то корректно отправляет заголовки и разархивирует полученные данные. В целом это реализуемо, но пока нет таких ресурсов времени у команды разработки, поэтому ищем более простой путь, если он есть...

Comment: думаю вы быстрей сами напишете. куча библиотке же есть. в случае наличия нестандартных приложений вы нахлебаетесь проблем еще.